# C - strcpy appears to be concatenating successive values stored in a struct

Tags: c, struct, strcpy

It's been a while since I have used C and am finding some issues in my code. I have a struct as such:

```
struct packet
{
char seq[4];
char type[4];
char src[10];
char dst[10];
char payload[MAX_BUF_LEN]; //predefined buffer length constant
}
```

Then when receiving a string of characters separated by spaces, I want to copy each of these "fields" into one of the corresponding `struct packet` variables. Here is what I have:

```
strcpy(temp_buf, buf);
field=strtok(temp_buf, " ");
```

Example string in `temp_buf`: "1 send 8273940124 9472849351 hello"

```
strcpy(inet_packet.seq, field);
field=strtok(NULL, " ");
strcpy(inet_packet.type, field);
field=strtok(NULL, " ");
strcpy(inet_packet.src, field);
field=strtok(NULL, " ");
strcpy(inet_packet.dst, field);
field=strtok(NULL, "\n");
printf("field: %s\n", field); //Shows field="hello"
strcpy(inet_packet.payload, field);
```

However, on the above example input, `inet_packet.type` = send82739501249472849351hello
So; it appears to be concatenating every successive copy into type? Have tried several different things but still fail to get the expected output.

Comment: To make it easy for others to help you, please compose and post an http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: You write that you have tried several different things. Please post everything you tried (with full source code), the output you received, and why it is not good for you.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to the problem you're having, but I noticed that three of your struct members (type, src and dest) are not big enough to contain both the strings you've provided and the null terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C strings must be NUL-terminated. So your declaration `char type[4]` is not large enough to hold the string `send` without overflowing.

Change this declaration to `char type[5]` and ensure that you do *not* put a string longer than 4 characters in there.

Comment: That did it. Unexpected behavior for what the root problem was, I thought that the strings would simply be chopped off at the end if that was the issue, good to know though. Thank you.

Comment: @user2950936: Yup. `strcpy()` is not very smart and will happily overwrite past the end of its destination buffer.